# Debian - Missing firmware bnx2 R610

Tags: debian, networking

Today I tried to install the non free Debian version in my Dell R610 [from this link](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/10.7.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-dvd/firmware-10.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso) which I hoped would solve my issue which I had with the free version. I reinstalled and tried the non-free version and yet I'm stuck again at:

[image]

However I did find out after I installed and completed the install that I could download the `.deb` but I'm not sure if this is the correct one: https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-bnx2

I'm not sure if my version is buster nor not.

This follows my question question. After that I have put the .deb into a USB stick and installed it on the server (`dpkg -i....`). Would this be enough to be able to get network back or do I need to config something more? I did try to find tutorials and youtube clips but none of them used Debian commands only (non GUI) so now I'm here asking and praying for an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only problem was the missing firmware, installing the appropriate firmware package should have fixed it, because its post-install procedure regenerated the initramfs. Reboot, or remove and reinsert the driver module to test it. If it still does not work, you'll have to provide more details (PCI ID and kernel logs) to enable further investigation.

Comment: Do you mean that the bnx2 would be fix after installing the Debian non-free version? Or do I need to manually install it first from: https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-bnx2 and then mount it through usb, dkfg -i ... and then reboot? And if it still doesnt work, how can I provide morr information since im pretty newbie with Linux.

Comment: I don't know whether the [unofficial Debian Installer with non-free firmware](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/) contains the firmware you seem to need; try it. Or follow the [official documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s04.en.html) and add this package to your official installer image. Or add the "non-free" repository to your installed system, and simply install the `firmware-bnx2` package (see https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for details). If it still doesn't work, search the output of `dmesg` for `firmware`.

Answer (score 1):

You must add appropriate debian package to the installed media. Here is [guide](https://www.mybluelinux.com/install-non-free-firmware-to-debian-linux-based-distros/) how to add firmware to debian iso cd/dvd.

**The most important thing is to have the correct installation package with right firmware in the *firmware* directory on the instalation media.**

Note: When you want create bootable usb drive from iso cd/dvd images, you can use [ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) open source tool.

If you want, I can create installation media for you and place it on some internet storage.